# What is the meaning of 'You're growing up'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, present-perfect, present-continuous

> “Really?” she’d said, a trace of sadness in her voice. “Really,
>   truly?” Billy and Papa nodded at the same time.
>
> “I’m Dad,” said Papa.
>
> Mama put her bag of school things on the floor, sat on a kitchen
>   chair, and pulled Billy to her. She hugged him, and in the most
>   natural way, said, “***I guess you’re growing up***.”
>
> “Yup,” he said, squirming away from the hug.

The above paragraph is from the *The Year of Billy Miller* What is the meaning of the bold sentence？Does it mean that Miller has grown up? Why does the writer use present continuous?

Comment: I think that growing up is a phrase rather than forming present continuous, but I did not find any references to prove that.

Answer (score 2):

This is partly a matter of opinion, but I think the author uses present continuous because Billy is **in the process of growing up** - that is, he is in the process of becoming more mature, but he is not fully grown yet.

In a larger, more idiomatic sense, Mama's remark can be interpreted as "I acknowledge that you are becoming more mature" - that is, that it is normal and natural that Billy should change.